# Comparing a plot of moving averages over different years in R language

Tags: r, time-series, moving-average

I would like a simple way in R to visualize moving average data and compare the evolution over the years.

For example, let's say I have a time series over 5 years and I plot the moving average :

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(tidyquant)
days <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2023-03-15"), by = "days")

# let's generate a series roughly linear with time with random noise and a seasonal effect
sales <- 2 * as.double(days) /1000 - sin(as.double(days) /365 *2 *3.14) + rnorm(1900)
 
data <- tibble(days, sales)
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(days, sales)) +
    geom_point(color = "grey") +
    geom_ma(ma_fun = SMA,linetype = 1, size = 1 , n = 14,color = "orange")
```

tidyquant:geom_ma is very convenient, I can fiddle with n to find the right span for the moving average and make it smooth. However, it can be difficult to tell apart the  seasonal effect from the trend.

What I would like is to have the same graphic , but overlaying all the sales figures over the span of one year (from 1/01 to 31/12), with a different color for the moving average of each year. I could then quickly see if there is a seasonal effect and a trend.

I understand I could calculate the moving_average in the data set, but it must be done before splitting by year for boundary reasons and it kind of defeats the purpose of having a simple geom_ma graph. On top of that, I failed to find an obvious function to do it.

How would you address this issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** *Added a moving average using the `slider` package. This specific code adds a moving average of order 5, but that's flexible.*

Using `gg_season` from the `feasts` package:

```r
library(fpp3)
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────────────────── fpp3 0.5 ──
#> ✔ tibble      3.2.1     ✔ tsibble     1.1.3
#> ✔ dplyr       1.1.0     ✔ tsibbledata 0.4.1
#> ✔ tidyr       1.3.0     ✔ feasts      0.3.0
#> ✔ lubridate   1.9.2     ✔ fable       0.3.2
#> ✔ ggplot2     3.4.1     ✔ fabletools  0.3.2
#> ── Conflicts ───────────────────────────────────────────────── fpp3_conflicts ──
#> ✖ lubridate::date()    masks base::date()
#> ✖ dplyr::filter()      masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ tsibble::intersect() masks base::intersect()
#> ✖ tsibble::interval()  masks lubridate::interval()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()         masks stats::lag()
#> ✖ tsibble::setdiff()   masks base::setdiff()
#> ✖ tsibble::union()     masks base::union()
library(slider)
days <- seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2023-03-15"), by = "days")

sales <- 2 * as.double(days) /1000 - sin(as.double(days) /365 *2 *3.14) + rnorm(1900)
data <- tibble(days, sales)

data %>%
  as_tsibble(index = days) %>%
  mutate(MA5 = slide_dbl(sales,
                              mean,
                              .before = 2,
                              .after = 2,
                              .complete = TRUE)) %>%
  gg_season(MA5, labels = 'both')
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`).
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`geom_text()`).
#> Removed 1 rows containing missing values (`geom_text()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hmm. I thought there was some parameters to specify a moving average, which there are not. So it's only answering half of the question.

Comment: Hi @Hugues the seasonal plot function doesn't offer than transformation directly. I've updated my answer to add a moving average column to the data frame which is then plotted.

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting for Hugues comment:

sure, since `geom_ma()` is based on the `SMA()` function, you can calculate the moving average prior to plotting, and this new `rolling_mean` will allow you to retain the previous end-of-year days to keep the average going, plotting `rolling_mean` instead of `sales`.  And instead of using `geom_ma()`, just use `geom_line()` since you are doing what `geom_ma()` would otherwise be doing, using SMA. The `SMA()` function has the n argument exactly as `geom_ma()` is set up. So you would just modify the n there.

```
data %>% 
    mutate(rolling_mean = SMA(sales, n = 14)) %>% 
    mutate(year = as_factor(year(days)),
    fake_date = ymd(paste("2020", month(days), day(days), sep = "-"))) %>% 
    #ggplot(aes(fake_date, sales, color = year)) +
    ggplot(aes(fake_date, rolling_mean, color = year)) +
    geom_point(color = "grey") +
    #geom_ma(ma_fun = SMA,linetype = 1, size = 1 , n = 14) +
    geom_line(size = 1) +
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d")
```

[image]

--- Leaving original post since issue is mainly with moving average ----

Kinda hacky but this: 1. makes year a factor, 2. assigns new year value to each date be same (leap) year (e.g., 2020), 3. plots new fake date only showing month/day labels and colors by years to spot seasonal trends.

```
data %>%
    mutate(year = as_factor(year(days)),
           fake_date = ymd(paste("2020", month(days), day(days), sep = "-"))) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(fake_date, sales, color = year)) +
    geom_point(color = "grey") +
    geom_ma(ma_fun = SMA,linetype = 1, size = 1 , n = 14) +
    scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %d")
```

[image]

Comment: An inconvenience of this solution, which can be minor or major depending on the number of days you're averaging, is that you are loosing the first days for every year.

Comment: ah, I see what you (rolling) mean, heh. I have adjusted the answer

Comment: @Hugues if answer looks correct then please accept